# how to get the data from fs.readfile callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

```js
const fs = require('fs');
let input = [];
fs.readFile('input.txt',(err,data)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    input = data.toString().split(' ');
})
console.log(input);
```

I wanted retrieve the data into input array but I am not getting it.

Comment: You can't access a variable inside a callback, it will be always `undefined` because you are trying to access before its get finished.

Comment: Your `console` won't wait that callback to finish. It fires before callback ends.

Comment: `console.log(input);` in callback function.

Comment: You should wrap with `Promise` and resolve the result inside the callback. Then do what you need.

Comment: thing is that whatever data i am getting , i wanted to get that data outside this function so, i can use that in my program but i am getting an empty array. just help me out in getting that data so that i can access it throughout my program

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`callbacks` functions means what do you want to do when data comes?

which means **node** will start read file and implement next line, without waiting data to came before implement your `console.log`.

You can make it as a function that returns `promise` like:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function getInput() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let input = [];
        fs.readFile('input.txt',(err,data)=>{
            if(err) return reject(err);
            var input = data.toString().split(' ');
            return resolve(input);
        })
    });
}

getInput().then(input => console.log(input));
```

or, you can use `async` and `await` to wait input, read more about [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).